# i want to make my text as a link in yii ckeditor. how to do it?

Tags: yii, ckeditor

This Is The Image Of Ckeditor where I need to make my text as link][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQeyp.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Link button in your editor, it looks like this: [image: CKEditor Link button]. [This CKEditor 3.x User's Guide article](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Users_Guide/Rich_Text/Links) describes how links work in CKEditor - it was written for CKEditor 3.x, but it works more or less the same in CKEditor 4.

*Last but not least, please do not post questions that include just an image, without any text. It's most recommended that you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you start posting on StackOverflow.*